# Get a file from user in php and send it to a flask server without saving it

Tags: php, python-3.x, curl, post, flask

I'm trying to send a file to a flask server by php curl what am I doing wrong here.

Here's the scenario:
- User visit my php application and upload a excel file
- My app send the file to a (python) flask app via php_curl

php code =========================

```
public function actiongetFileSendIt(){
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { 
    $cFile = curl_file_create($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['type'],'file');
    } else {
       $cFile = '@' . realpath($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].';filename='.$_FILES['file']['name'].';type='.$_FILES['file']['type']);
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/pos/import");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cFile);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";exit("Ends Here");
}
```

python code =======================

```
if 'file' not in request.files: // php request fails here
    current_app.logger.info(f"request.files 1 {request.files}")
    current_app.logger.error('File not found')
    return resp
file = request.files['file']
if not file.filename:
    current_app.logger.info(f"request.files 2 {request.files}")
    current_app.logger.error('Invalid file type found')
    return resp
if file:
    current_app.logger.info(f"request.files 3 {request.files}")
```

============== LOGS =============

Working curl post

```
curl -X POST   http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/pos/import   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'   -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'   -H 'postman-token: 73b974f1-3e3f-713d-2a34-a1abeb3d9a80'   -F 'file=@/home/anubavam/Downloads/Corrected_Regulations MA YOGA.xlsx'
{
  "success": "Plan of study import completed"
}
```

python log

```
request.files 3 ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'Corrected_Regulations MA YOGA.xlsx' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```

Not working php curl post's python log

```
request.files 1 ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Question 1 : How to get the file from user in php $_FILES and turn it into a curl post.
Question 2 : How to make a php curl post to flask with key value pair like {'file':/path/or/whatever/from/question1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. In case if someone wants to handle this situation

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { 
                        $cFile = curl_file_create($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                      } else {
                        $cFile = '@' . realpath($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                    }
                    $post = array('file'=> $cFile);
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/pos/import");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
                    curl_close ($ch);
```